# How can I call findViewById inside IntentService?

Tags: android, intentservice

Is there a way to call `findViewById` inside IntentService? In my case, I tried using a static reference of MainActivity class. But it didn't work.

MainActivity class calls IntentService:

```
public static MainActivity mA;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mA=this;
        startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class).setAction("MyIntent"));
    }
```

And MyService class is:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction()=="MyIntent"){
            ListView lv=(ListView)(MainActivity.mA.findViewById(R.id.listView));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (MainActivity.mA.findViewById(R.id.listView)).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }

    }
```

This gives a NullPointerException. I verified that MainActivity.mA is OK inside the service class. But still, I cannot call `findViewById`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: what is ur listView contain?

Comment: listView is the id of <ListView>

Comment: what does that mean? i mean to say is list view contain any value..this part:-(MainActivity.mA.findViewById(R.id.listView)).toString()

Comment: Please post your logcat..